# How can I render a tube with opacity distribution with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

**I want to render a tube with opacity distribution**, which looks as the translucency of the outer tube is larger than that of the inner. How can I make such kind of tube with three.js?

I tried combining multiple semitransparent tubes with different radius. It worked, but took too long time to render.
I did the following:

```
var tubeSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);
var tubeNum = 32;

var tubeGeometry;
var geometries = [];
for (let i = 0; i < tubeNum; i++) {
    const geometryTmp = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(
                                        tubeSpline,
                                        5 * data.length,
                                        (1 / tubeNum) * (i + 1),
                                        32,
                                        false);
    geometries.push(geometryTmp);
}
tubeGeometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);
var tubeShaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShaderSimple').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
    uniforms: {
        points: {value: positions},
        radiuses: {value: radiuses},
        colors: {value: colors},
        size: {value: data.length},
        texture: {value: texture},
        lightPosition: {value: new THREE.Vector3(-20, 40, 60)},
        viewVector: { value: camera.position }
    },
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    clipping: true,
    clippingPlanes: [clippingPlane]
});
tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, tubeShaderMaterial);
scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

I could realize a tube with a vague appearance by the above code, but too slow. **Are there any ideas to render a tube with opacity distribution faster?**

Comment: Can you post a live example of your working project in https://jsfiddle.net/ or via [a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? It could be a lot of different factors outside of your code above. Also, what do you mean "too slow"? Are you getting low FPS, or does it take too long for the geometry to initialize?

Comment: @Marquizzo Thank you for your comment, Marquizzo. I cannot post [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistletoe/qvpd1c5b/) properly (cannot render), but uploaded the whole source code and sample data to [github](https://github.com/MistletoeNaoko/TimeTubes_Browser). `TimeTubes_Browser/js/TimeTubes.js` is the main code for creating a tube. Also, it seems that it takes long time to create multiple TubeBufferGeometry. Therefore, I think it's better to realize a vague tube without creating so many tubes if I can.